# MySQL query returns no results at night, with no errors thrown

Tags: php, mysql

I have a master and slave database, which is checked via the below code every 5 minutes. For roughly 30 minutes every night (after midnight, so should be low load), the slave DB has no results in the table I'm checking.

MysqliWrapper is just a wrapper for Mysqli class to provide a singleton and query generation. The query generated is just `select * from LogTable order by id DESC limit 0,1`

I've added checks to see if there are connection errors, or errors with the query, neither of which are logging anything at the time this happens.

I've tried selecting from a different table, which returned results fine, and also tried `select now()`, all of which works.

```php
<?php
$masterDB = MysqliWrapper::singleton('host1', 'username', 'password', 'dbname');
$slaveDB = MysqliWrapper::singleton('host2', 'username', 'password', 'dbname');

if ($masterDB->connect_errno) {
    Log::error('masterDB error: '.$masterDB->connect_error);
}

if ($slaveDB->connect_errno) {
    Log::error('slaveDB error: '.$slaveDB->connect_error);
}

$filters = [];
$limits = [0, 1];
$orderBy = 'id DESC';

$masterLog = LogTable::staticFind($filters, $limits, $orderBy);

if(empty($masterLog)) {
    Log::error('masterDB query: no results found');
}

if ($masterDB->errno) {
    Log::error('masterDB query error: '.$masterDB->error);
}

$registry = new Registry();
$registry->set('customDb', $slaveDB);
$slaveLog = LogTable::staticFind($filters, $limits, $orderBy);

if(empty($slaveLog)) {
    Log::error('slaveDB query: no results found');
}

if ($slaveDB->errno) {
    Log::error('slaveDB query error: '.$slaveDB->error);
}
```

As I say, this works fine 95% of the time through the day, but it's failing to select anything from the slaveDB at about 1am for 30 minutes, then it starts working again fine. No errors are logged, nothing I can find anyway.

Comment: What is kept in the LogTable? Is LogTable the only table effected? Is there any maintenance being ran on the DB at night? Have you checked your Mysql logs?

Comment: Log table is written to multiple times a minute, but there shouldn't be any activity at this time of night. LogTable seems to be the only one affected. MySQL logs are showing nothing in this time period.
Could a table lock cause a 0 results query?

Comment: How big is the LogTable out of interest? Are you sure there is no scheduled tasks being ran against the DB during the time you observe this behaviour? The fact that it is always at about 1am seems to indicate it is some kind of scheduled event.

Comment: There is an hourly back up via mysqldump, which I ruled out because I'd expect this to have problems every single hour if it was the cause, rather than once a day

Comment: It is a fairly large table though, 10s of GBs

Comment: Are you on a shared hosting environment or a dedicated server?

Comment: @tshimkus it's a rackspace VM, so not exactly shared but not sure how walled off it is

Comment: If the nightly blackout period is not being caused by some scheduled task you are running it could possibly be your host or one of the other users on your machine. You are sharing resources like memory and processing with other web services and there is a chance that the activity is happening outside of something you control.